# showing error while update record with empty field using parametrized query with vb script in asp classic

Tags: sql, vbscript, parameters, asp-classic

When I update record through update statement with some empty fields using parametrized query and VBScript in Classic ASP page, its showing error and not updating.

error is:

```
ADODB.Parameters (0x800A0E7C)

Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete 
information was provided.
```

but when I fill all field and update its updating. my code is blew given:

```vb
<%
Dim objRS, objCmd, str

Set objCmd  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'@lankymart  i have edited code as below

'=========================
str = "update admin set Astate=?, Acity=?, Acenterid=?, Aname=?, gender=?, Acontact=?, Aemail=?,  ACreatedBy=? where Aid=?"
If Len(dt) > 0 Then
strU = strU & ", Acdate=? "
else
strU = strU & ""
end if
strU = strU & "where Aid=?"
'========================== 

'above code is working fine as its escaping when i pass null value but i want to update null value in record too. null value is not updating in record. please help me  

With objCmd
.ActiveConnection = MM_connDUdirectory_STRING
.CommandText = str
.CommandType = adCmdText

.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg1", adInteger, adParamInput, ,StrStateID))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg2", adInteger, adParamInput, ,StrCityID))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg3", adInteger, adParamInput, ,StrCenterID))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg4", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(StrName)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg5", adVarChar, adParamInput, 6))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg6", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(StrContno)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg7", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(StrMail)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg8", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(a_name)))
 If Len(dt) > 0 Then
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg9", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(dt)))
end if
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg10", adInteger, adParamInput, ,StaffId))

.Parameters("@paramg1").Value = StrStateID
.Parameters("@paramg2").Value = StrCityID
.Parameters("@paramg3").Value = StrCenterID
.Parameters("@paramg4").Value = StrName
.Parameters("@paramg5").Value = StrGender
.Parameters("@paramg6").Value = StrContno
.Parameters("@paramg7").Value = StrMail
.Parameters("@paramg8").Value = a_name
 If Len(dt) > 0 Then
.Parameters("@paramg9").Value = dt
end if
.Parameters("@paramg10").Value = StaffId

end with 
Set objRS = objCmd.Execute()
%>
```

When I submit all values, then its updating but when I submit some fields than its showing me error as above written but it should update without any error. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `UPDATE` statement that expects 10 parameters then you have to pass 10 parameters. This means populating the Parameters `.Value` or specifying the value during the `CreateParameter()` method, failing to do this will give you the error you experienced.

If you need the `UPDATE` to be dynamic build the query along with the parameters as you check the value is being passed.

> **IMPORTANT:**
>
> This code snippet is **not** a complete solution, it just demonstrates how to structure building your Query String and Parameters in a dynamic fashion.

```vb
str = "update admin set "

'Further down while defining parameters
If Len(StrStateID & "") > 0 Then
  str = str & "Astate=?, "
  .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg1", adInteger, adParamInput, ,StrStateID))
End If

'Repeat for Parameters 2 - 8
'...

'Then on your last parameter (in the SET statement)
If Len(dt & "") > 0 Then
  str = str & "Acdate=? " 'Notice no comma
  .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg9", adVarChar, adParamInput, len(dt)))
  .Parameters("@paramg9").Value = dt
End If

str = str & "where Aid=?"

'Don't forgot the remaining Parameter for the WHERE clause
'This should always be passed or the code will fail.
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@paramg10", adInteger, adParamInput, ,StaffId))
```

---

> **Note:**
>   There are more efficient ways of producing this like using an `Array` to build your expected parameter fields and values then dynamically building up the query and the `Parameter` objects using a `For` loop.

Comment: i edited with your code but its showing error "Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01F9)
Invalid or unqualified reference" at line of ".Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter..."

Comment: @lokeshpurohit You can't just use that code, I was giving the "gist" of what you need to do. You still need your code or no references to the `Parameters` etc will work. Look at adding it into your code and if your still having problems post your updated code into the original question and I'll try and help.

Comment: @lokeshpurohit Remember you will still need to define `Parameter("@paramg10")` or your `WHERE` clause will fail. Will update answer to highlight this.

Comment: i have edited code above pls have a look. its working fine when i pass null value its not showing error but same value i want to update in record too. please help me how

Comment: @lokeshpurohit You haven't followed my instructions, you need to build your query string (`str`) as you check what values should be passed (`If Len(YourValue & "") > 0 Then`). You can't just do one `Parameter` and expect it to work, it needs to be done for any `Parameters` that can be passed as NULL. Which is why you still have an issue.